Proving the Bolzano-Weierstrass Theorem with the Axiom of Completeness directly
The original question.
Hi everyone, I got this question from the book “Understanding Analysis” by Stephen Abbott, and I have a question:
What if the first term of the sequence was far away from the rest of the sequence? For example, the first term could be one and the rest of the terms could be within the interval [4,9]. Wouldn’t this make the sequence have no subsequence that converges to sup(S)?
The solution manual didn’t help at all, or maybe I just don’t understand it... But here it is anyway:
The solution, from the solution manual.

Your example would not violate that. Convergence only depends on the asymptotic behavior of the sequence. You can therefore change as many sequence members as you like without changing the limit value or the convergence behavior of the sequence.

Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Perhaps here is a slightly different proof.
Let $\epsilon>0$ be arbitrary and define $s:=\sup S<\infty$. By definition of $S$, there are infinitely many $a_n$ with $s-\epsilon<a_n$ but only finitely many (or none) with $s+\epsilon<a_n$. This means that there must be an infinite number of $a_n$ with $s-\epsilon<a_n<s+\epsilon$, i.e. $$|a_n-s|<\epsilon\;\mathrm{ for \;infinite\; many\; n\in \mathbb N.}$$
Now you can inductively define a subsequence by choosing a $n_k\in \mathbb N$ for each $k\in \mathbb N$ with $$|a_{n_k}-s|<\frac1k$$(apply the equation above with $\epsilon=\frac1k$).
And voila, your subsequence $(a_{n_k})_k$ converges to $s$.
